# Saving Authentication Tokens to Third-Party Websites

Tags: encryption, authentication, token

So Flickr allows you to authenticate users to your app via app_key and secret and returns an authentication token. I want to securely save that authentication token in my database, but also be able to reverse it so that the application can make authenticated calls for that user. I'm not sure what's the best way to do that or if that's what I should be doing at all? I want to persist that authentication token so that when a user logs back into my site, it'll already have the authentication token.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that storing the plaintext authorization tokens in a database is not a problem but there are some other aspects that are more critical in keeping the tokens (and use of them) safe.

Make sure the `oauth_consumer_key` (app key) and `oauth_token` (authorization token) are never sent to or stored at the clients side (the users browser, phone, etc.). This means that the requests to the Service provider (Flickr) must always be done from a server that has access to the database and then the data received from the Service provider data can be forwarded to the client. If you store the key and token at the users side, then they will be able to impersonate your application and access restricted data.

To secure the key and tokens during the request from your server to Flickr, do the request as a POST over HTTPS. This way an eavesdropper cannot get hands on your tokens while they are on their way to Flickr.

Secure your database, not by encrypting the tokens, but by making sure that any unauthorized access to the database is not possible. If your database gets compromised (eg. SQL injection, any other injection) then the earlier measures don't really have any effect. This is a good thing to do in general, and I'd advice it over you encrypting the tokens in the database.

Sources: [OAUTH v1.0](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) and the [Flickr authentication API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html).

Comment: Hey Juha, that makes sense from a security to attacks point of view and yeah I have secure requests going out to Flickr done server-side. Client never sees the api key or any key really. I think my concern was that I would have access to anyone's flickr who authenticates it with my site. Is there a way that I can keep these tokens safe from myself? Like if I was a client, I would be concerned about this right?

Comment: Oh, yes that makes sense. But ultimately someone is going to have the database root privileges, the key for decryption, or some other ultimate access to the database and it's contents, so it becomes more of a legal issue. The best advice i have is for you to carefully read the privacy and terms of service of Flickr and familiarize yourself with your countrys relevant regulations since usually personal data are quite strongly regulated. I wish there is some crypto way to do all of this in a way that gives you complete deniability, but i don't know of anything like that.

Comment: Alright thanks. So conclusion: auth tokens are generally safe to be stored directly. Read terms on personal data to make sure everything is ok because there will be at minimum one root access user to the database so deniability will be hard.

Comment: Yes, auth tokens are generally safe (in the Flickr case) when stored clear in the database. I forgot to add the part where i say "I'm not a lawyer", so: I'm not a lawyer, don't take my advice for valid legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that you can save a hash key client side in a session/cookie. This basically means that anyone one the server will not be able to do anything with any information because they don't have the map that says this person is connected with this api/property. So client has 1 half of the key, and server has the other half of the key. I would hash this with something like email+password, password being the key. The only problem with that is synchronizing the properties when passwords inevitably change. I like this half-key approach and would like to apply it to other ways. It would be cool to create a database that is public, but impossible to get any valuable information from without the other half of the "key". I don't know, it also looks like we're moving away from "entry passwords" altogether though.